# Laravel 4 textarea

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, laravel, laravel-4

The problem is the laravel `Form::textarea`. When I enter let's say 5 paragraphs of Lorem ipsum generated words, it'll just display text which has like 5 sentences(or even less). I have an custom 'box' (div):

```
.doc-content-box{
position:relative;
min-height: 1px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
background: #F9F9F9;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
border-radius: 1px;
}
```

I've also tried changing it to div class="well" (i'm using bootstrap), and it doesn't work. any hints?

here's an image:

[image]

Comment: have you got any more code or a link to the site or a fiddle?

Comment: @Vector
I don't have a link or a fiddle, tell me what do you need? I have some sort of system for creating new posts/news.

Comment: Looking at your image there is clearly a limit set on characters, i would assume at a `php` level. It isn't an overflow problem as the text is stopping midway. The problem is not within code you have posted but within the `php`

Comment: @Vector
Oh, maybe because I'm using VARCHAR for the textarea, which is 255 letters? How could I change it?

Comment: You change it in phpmyadmin, the menu at the to that says structure, then edit the column details

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by changing the type into database to `mediumtext`.